# StringUtils Dudas

Tags: java, string

tengo que realizar una comprobación. Tengo que buscar un email a través de un nif/dni.
La cosa es que necesito quitarle la letra del dni para buscar un email asociado a dicho dni.

He estado revisando la clase StringUtils, ya la he utilizado en otras ocasiones.
La cosa es que con el split necesitas un carácter de separación para indicarle por donde cortar la cadena.
¿Alguien me podría indicar como podría hacer, para que me quite el ultimo carácter del dni y compruebe que es una letra lo que quita?

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola y bienvenido [es.so]. Es posible que te falte añadir la etiqueta del lenguaje que estás utilizando ("Java") Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). Es importante también realizar el [tour] y leer [ask], creando un ejemplo mínimo, para que la comunidad te pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu buscas : `charAt()`

El método devuelve el carácter en el índice especificado en una cadena.

`char letraDNI = dni.charAt(dni.length() - 1);`

Creo que ya podrás jugar con eso.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Estuve mirándolo también con charAt(), finalmente lo hice con un if que comprueba si dni (IsNumber) es numero solo, lo deja como esta. Si en la cadena no hay solo números. Que me quite el ultimo carácter (nif.substring(0, nif.length()-1))

Comment: No es necesario comprobar el DNI entero, con evaluar el último caracter es suficiente. Podrías reemplazar el DNI entero del `if` por `nif.charAt(nif.length() - 1)`. Con esto tu algoritmo sería (en teoría) unas 8 veces más veloz, ya que `isNumber` funciona como un bucle que evalúa los caracteres uno por uno.

Answer (score 1):

eso sucede con algunos caracteres especiales por ejemplo . ó , ó \ son varios

debe utilizar un Patern así:

```
String.split(Pattern.quote("//"));
```